# Managing 404 error

Tags: php, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

I am making a MVC website without framework. Could you help me write the code in the class autoload in order to redirect to a 404 error page (exists already) when a class does not exist.

http://cedricjager.com/stream/index.php?p=non_existant_class =>404 page

```
class Autoload {

static function register() {
spl_autoload_register (['Autoload', 'myAutoload']);
}

static function myAutoload($class_name) {
$class = ucfirst($class_name);
require 'Models/' . $class . '.php';
}
}

class Router {.....
    elseif ($p === '404') {
  $this->controller->error();
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. Make your own custom 404 page
2. [Make an .htaccess](http://www.spunkyjones.com/how-to-create-a-htaccess-file/) file and place it in your root
3. Place this line inside the .htaccess file ErrorDocument 404 {your website link}/your-custom-404.php

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be to use [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php), i.e.

```
if(file_exists('Models/' . $class . '.php')) {
  require 'Models/' . $class . '.php';
} else {
  header('Location: 404.php');
}
```

That should do the trick for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope it code can help you

```
static function myAutoload($class_name)
{
    $class = ucfirst($class_name);
    $file = "Models/{$class}.php";
    try {
        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            throw new Exception('File doesn\'t exists', 404);
        }
        require $file;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $message = $e->getMessage(); // File doesn't exists
        $code = $e->getCode(); //404
        // show your 404 error
        // or rewrite to 404 url
    }
}
```